# Когда клиент в eureka был завершен неправильно он продолжает висеть со статусом UP

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, eureka

При не корректном завершении работы приложения в моём случае я просто убиваю процесс.

Клиент продолжает оставаться в эврике, будто он активен.

Как это решается?

Конфиг discovery-serivce

```
eureka:
  environment: ${SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}
  instance:
    hostname: ${HOST_NAME}
    metadataMap:
      zone: ${ZONE}
    appname: ${INSTANCE_NAME}
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 90
    prefer-ip-address: false
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${SERVICE_DISCOVERY_URL}
  server:
    renewal-threshold-update-interval-ms: 900000
    enable-self-preservation: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем было принято решение переключить **enable-self-preservation** в **false**